# Filter not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

```
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            String charString = charSequence.toString();
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                FilteredData = ArrayData;
            } else {
                ArrayList<Data> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Data checkData: ArrayData) {

                    if (checkData.getNames().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {
                        filteredList.add(checkData);
                    }
                }
                FilteredData = filteredList;
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = FilteredData;
            return filterResults;
        }
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            FilteredData = (ArrayList<Data>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

This is my data Object:

```
public class Data {
public String names;
public String cPoints;
public Double latitude;
public Double longitude;
public String code;
public Float distance;
public Integer spots;
public int scale = 2;
public Data(String n, String cP, Double lat, Double lon, String c, Float dis, Integer sp ){
    names = n;
    cPoints = cP;
    latitude = lat;
    longitude = lon;
    code = c;
    distance = dis;
    spots = sp;
}
public String getNames(){
    return names;
}
public String getcPoints(){
    return cPoints;
}
public Double getLatitude(){
    return latitude;
}
public Double getLongitude(){
    return longitude;
}
public String getCode(){
    return code;
}
public Integer getSpots(){
    return spots;
}
public Double getDistance(){
    return Math.round(distance * Math.pow(10, scale)) / Math.pow(10, scale);
}
```

}
The data object is used to connect items of a single parkinggarage to each other

I've created this filter, and I call it this way: `adapter.getFilter.filter(newText)` but somehow my adapter RecyclerView doesn't change, could anyone help me fix this?

Comment: see [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85) generic adapter - note `matches()` method which is used for filtering purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need do some modifications in your code. you inserting new filtered data into different arrylist so after you calling notifydatasetchanged() it will not filter your data.

First declare old list data into another list variable then do change like below

```
 public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    AllData = ArrayData;
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
         ArrayData = AllData;
    } else {
        ArrayData.clear();
        for (String s : AllData) {
            if (s.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                ArrayData.add(s);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then call this filter method in your Search.

Hope this helpful..

@ Rajesh

Comment: String s should be Data s --> also this doesn't work it doesn't show me any results. It shows nothing in my recyclerview

Comment: Can you explain what is data here. Is it a model class with String variables?

Comment: Check the first post. I posted "Data" there

Comment: If you want filter data with names then avoid foreach loop and use

 for (int i=0; i< AllData.size(); i++) {
            if (AllData.get(i).getNames().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                ArrayData.add(s);
            }
        }

Comment: @Sanderbakker if you used my generic adapter your problem would be solved long time ago... whats unclear in it? why do you want a custom filter for every adapter you write?

Comment: @pskink For me it's unclear how I implement your code inside my code

Comment: @Sanderbakker `class MyAdapter extends MatchableRVArrayAdapter<Data, MyAdapter.VH> { ...`, just override `matches()` method, thats all

Comment: @pskink Ah okay I understand now. One more thing. What should I put inside Override public boolean matches(){}? Also I'm getting the error "there is no default constructor available, and that it should implement onbindView

Comment: @Sanderbakker return true or false if true the item matches your filtering criteria and is appended to the filtered items

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141985/discussion-between-sander-bakker-and-pskink).